# junit4 inner class method is not calling

Tags: java, junit4

The below code is not calling the inner class test method.
since @RunWith does not support mutilple class delcaration that is why i using the inner class.
The main idea is to create a dynamic test method using Parameterized.class. So each method is is taken a new test

```
@RunWith(ScenarioStepRunner.class)
public class TestGlobal extends Step_Common{
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // some pre test code
    }

    @Test
    public void subRunner() {
        JUnitCore.runClasses(ParameterizedRunner.class);
    }

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class ParameterizedRunner  extends Step_Common{

        @Parameter(0)
        public String name;

        @Parameters(name = "Tetsing {0}")
        public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { "AA" }, { "BB" } });
        }

        @Test
        public void test() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("*********" + this.name);
            
        }

    }

}
```